# Screen shot of all google.com oneboxes

Tags: interaction-design, design-patterns, search, documentation

Can anyone provide the URL for an illustration of an exhaustive set of google.com oneboxes?

Background: Below is a [SERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_results_page) screen shot highlighting google.com's way of grouping content types, which [some](http://searchengineland.com/meet-the-google-onebox-plus-box-direct-answers-the-10-pack-26706) [documentation](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/oneboxguide/oneboxguide.html) refer to as oneboxes. I'm looking for an exhaustive screen shot; in other words an illustration showing all (or most) of google.com's oneboxes in a single image.

I have seen this illustration previously; I believe some type of food (pizza?) was used as a query term. The author made it clear that google.com never uses all of the oneboxes together. Rather, the effort was to make an illustrative table of contents of what SERP elements was made available to users across searches.

[image: google.com oneboxes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. It was taco, not pizza. Thumbnail below, go to [the original article](https://moz.com/blog/mega-serp-a-visual-guide-to-google) for full resolution.

[image: All google.com oneboxes]